# Create a Slipstream package of my additional Help content for AX 2012 Help Server

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I would like the create a Slipstream package of my additional Help content, for a customizes installation medium of the AX 2012 R3 Help Server.

According to the MS documentation this should be possible for Help content updates. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378076.aspx
But how do I create these packages from my Help content sides?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't make it clear, but it looks like you just put your *.MSI in `[InstallMedia]\Msi\HelpContent\EN-US\` or whatever language folder you want.

I went to that directory and just copied the *.msi in place and you can see it has a second item now showing up.

According to [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378076.aspx) you provided, it says you choose updates in the "Language and content selection" which is what my change did.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Real poorly documented by Microsoft. Actually, I would have expected that there would have to be deposited for similar Cumulative Updates in the Updates folder. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'll say that I got very lucky figuring this out.